# Gherkin in Behat and input validations scenarios

Tags: bdd, gherkin, behat

I am using Gherkin in Behat and I face an input problem in the validation scenario. Here is the example of the scenario I wrote, but Behat doesn't understand the difference between variable definition in Tags `<variable>` and test invalid input like special characters of tags `<testspecialchar>`

Scenario Outline:
- Incorrect entry at input variable
- Given user logged with username "sh" and password "123"
- When user enter incorrect data at `<input variable>`
- Then the user will have

Examples:

```
|    input variable   |       validation message     |
| <testspecialchar>   |    please, enter valid entry |
|  test<specialchar   |         incorrect entry      |
|  test>specialchar   |         incorrect entry      |
```

Could anyone try this before and have solution for that problem?
Thanks for support :)
Shimaa

Comment: Could you show us your scenario steps and step defs you are implementing. Issue could be in there but can't know unless more is known.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK to use these kind of special characters (the ones used by Gherkin) it's needed to escape with a "\" backslash.

I hope this helps